# how to call slider in cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp

i need to add slider for div containing images in cakephp.I have tried the sample code in jqueryEngine helper.

```
Controller.php

App::uses('JqueryEngineHelper', 'Helper'); 
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
var $helpers = array('Js');

$this->Js->slider(array(
   'complete' => 'onComplete',
   'change' => 'onChange',
   'min' => 0,
   'max' => 10,
   'value' => 2,
   'direction' => 'vertical',
   'wrapCallbacks' => false
));
```

But this is not working.I am getting the error as

> Call to a member function slider() on a non-object

Please guide me where i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Did you even try to google for the error message? It is *very* clear what is wrong here. Also this error is a felt 1000 times asked here before.

> Call to a member function slider() on a non-object

Looks like the JsHelper is not loaded and because of that you get a "non-object". Load the JsHelper. If that doesn't help you need to figure out why.